# Understanding a theorem in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

*Theorem:* Let $X$ be projective, $Y$ be quasi-projective variety, and $f: X \to Y$ be an algebraic morphism. Then the image $f(X)\subset Y$ is Zariski closed.

I am trying to understand my note that says that the claim fails in the example: $X=\mathbb{C}^2, Y=\mathbb{C}^2$ and $f=(x,y) \mapsto (x,xy).$ I think each hypothesis is satisfied except that $\mathbb{C}^2$ is **not** a projective algebraic variety since it sits as an open set in $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^2$. Is this correct?

Besides, are there other conditions under which the image would be Zariski closed? Is there any statement like "image of an algebraic morphism is Zariski closed if and only if $\cdots$"?

Comment: Indeed $\Bbb{C}^2$ is not projective.

Comment: Thanks! (I have edited my post to include an additional question at the end.)

Comment: $\mathbb C^2$ is not projective because there are nonconstant regular functions on it.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, you only need to show that $f$ is a closed map (that is, the image of every closed set is closed).

Now in this situation, one can prove much stronger result: $f$ is proper.

This is because $X$ is proper and $Y$ is separated, and apply Hartshorne Corollary II.4.8(e).

Comment: I completely missed what you are saying here. Are you answering my questions on the last para of my post? Or giving a proof that $\mathbb{C}^2$ is not projective?

Comment: @monomorphic I am answering the question why the image of $f$ is closed.